# GLSL Fragment shader slowdown

Tags: glsl, shader, slowdown

I have been spending the last few days writing a fragment shader that will handle the background for a 2d game im making. However, today I noticed that my cloud rendering is extremley slow (drop from 3000 to 300 fps) when rendering.

At first I thought that it was because I had done something stupid when generating the clouds, but after some experiments I noticed that the slowdown only happned when I added the clouds t the gl_FragColor. Calculating them seemed to not have any impact on performance.

I generate the clouds like this:

```
float rand(vec2 co){
  return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

float hash( float n ) //Borrowed from voltage
{
    return fract(sin(n)*43758.5453);
}

float fBmWRand( vec2 p )//Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
    float f = 0.0;
    f += 0.50000*rand( p ); p = p*2.02;
    f += 0.25000*rand( p ); p = p*2.03;
    f += 0.12500*rand( p ); p = p*2.01;
    f += 0.06250*rand( p ); p = p*2.04;
    f += 0.03125*rand( p );
    return f/0.984375;
}

float noise( in vec2 x )//Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
vec2 p = floor(x);
vec2 f = fract(x);
    f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    float n = p.x + p.y*57.0;
    float res = mix(mix( hash(n+  0.0), hash(n+  1.0),f.x), mix( hash(n+ 57.0), hash(n+ 58.0),f.x),f.y);
    return res;
}

float fbm( vec2 p ) //Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
        float f = 0.0;
        f += 0.50000*noise( p ); p = p*2.02;
        f += 0.25000*noise( p ); p = p*2.03;
        f += 0.12500*noise( p ); p = p*2.01;
        f += 0.06250*noise( p ); p = p*2.04;
        f += 0.03125*noise( p );
        return f/0.984375;
}

vec3 bgGradient()
{
    //Getting the height of the current pixel
    float height = gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y;

    //Calculating the brightness of the pixel
    float brightness = 1.0 - 0.4 * height;

    //Combining everything into a background
    vec3 grad = vec3(1., 1., 1.);// * brightness;
    return grad;
}

bool star()
{
/*//Getting a position to run random calculations with
float pos = (gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x) * (gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y) + 0.5;

if(hash(pos) < 0.001)
{
    return true;
}
return false*/;

if(fBmWRand(gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy) < 0.08)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}

float cloudFadeDist = 0.1; //The distance at which the clouds will start fading away

vec4 clouds( vec2 point )
{
vec4 result = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);

//Checking if the cloud is above
float fbmResult = fbm(point * 5.);
if(fbmResult > overcast)
{
    result = vec4(fbmResult, fbmResult, fbmResult, 1.0);
    //result = vec4(1., 1., 1., 1.);
}
else if(fbmResult > overcast - (cloudFadeDist / resFact)) //Outlining the clouds
{
    float dist = overcast - fbmResult;
    float colorFac = 1.0 - dist / (cloudFadeDist / resFact);

    if(colorFac > 0.0001)
    {
        result = vec4(fbmResult, fbmResult, fbmResult, colorFac);
    }
}

//Finer details
float fbmDetail = fbm(point * 20.);
vec4 details = vec4( 0.7 + fbmDetail, 0.7 + fbmDetail, 0.7 + fbmDetail, 1.0);

//result = mix(result, details, result.a);
result = result * details;
result = result * details;

return result;
}
```

And I add the clouds to the rest of the "image" with this

```
//Generating the clouds
vec4 cloudLayer = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //clouds( (15.0 * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy + posX * float(i + 1));
    /*vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2((15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1)),
                        (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResoulution.y);*/

    vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2( (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1),
        (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y + posY * float(i + 1)));

    //finalColor = finalColor + vec4(cloud, 1.);
    cloudLayer = mix(cloudLayer, cloud, cloud.a);
}

if(time > nStart || time < nEnd) //Nighttime
{
    finalColor = finalColor * nSky;

    finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer.a);

    cloudLayer = cloudLayer * nCloud;
    //finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
    vec4 genericColor = cloudLayer;
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
    //finalColor = vec4(nSky.r, nSky.g, nSky.b, 1.0);
}
else if(time > dStart && time < dEnd)
{
    finalColor = finalColor * dSky;

    //cloudLayer = cloudLayer * dCloud;
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
}
else if(time > dEnd && time < nStart) //Evening
{
    float timeFact = (time - dEnd) / (nStart - dEnd);

    //Calculating the diffirence between night and day
    vec4 skyDiff = vec4(nSky.r - dSky.r, nSky.g - dSky.g, nSky.b - dSky.b, 1.);
    vec4 skyColor = vec4(dSky.r + (skyDiff.r * timeFact), dSky.g + (skyDiff.g * timeFact), dSky.b + (skyDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);

    finalColor = skyColor;

    //Stars
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer * timeFact);

    //Clouds
    vec4 cloudDiff = vec4(nCloud.r - dCloud.r, nCloud.g - dCloud.g, nCloud.b - dCloud.b, 1.);
    vec4 cloudColor = vec4(dCloud.r + (cloudDiff.r * timeFact), dCloud.g + (cloudDiff.g * timeFact), dCloud.b + (cloudDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);
    vec4 cloudLayer = cloudLayer * cloudColor;
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
}
else if(time > nEnd && time < dStart) //Evening
{
    float timeFact = (time - nEnd) / (dStart - nEnd);

    //Calculating the diffirence between night and day
    vec4 skyDiff = vec4(dSky.r - nSky.r, dSky.g - nSky.g, dSky.b - nSky.b, 1.);
    vec4 skyColor = vec4(nSky.r + (skyDiff.r * timeFact), nSky.g + (skyDiff.g * timeFact), nSky.b + (skyDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);

    finalColor = skyColor;

    //Stars
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer * 1. - timeFact);

    //Clouds
    vec4 cloudDiff = vec4(dCloud.r - nCloud.r, dCloud.g - nCloud.g, dCloud.b - nCloud.b, 1.);
    vec4 cloudColor = vec4(nCloud.r + (cloudDiff.r * timeFact), nCloud.g + (cloudDiff.g * timeFact), nCloud.b + (cloudDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);
    vec4 cloudLayer = cloudLayer * cloudColor;
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
}
gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

The slowdown only happens when I do:

```
gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

I also double the FPS from 300 to 600 if I remove the details part of the cloud generation

Is there something I have done wrong or is it just natural for the shader to be this performance intensive when I do something like this.

For reference, this is the whole shader

```
    uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform vec2 iMouse;

uniform float time;

uniform float overcast;
uniform float posX;
uniform float posY;

uniform vec4 dSky; //The color of the sky during the day
uniform vec4 nSky; //The color of the sky during the night

uniform vec4 dCloud; //The color of the clouds at day
uniform vec4 nCloud; //The color of the clouds at night

float resFact = iResolution.x / 500;

//float overcast = iMouse.y / iResolution.y;
//float posX = iMouse.x / iResolution.x;

/*float nSkyR = 0.05;
float nSkyG = 0.05;
float nSkyB = 0.39;*/

float rand(vec2 co){
  return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

float hash( float n ) //Borrowed from voltage
{
    return fract(sin(n)*43758.5453);
}

float fBmWRand( vec2 p )//Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
        float f = 0.0;
        f += 0.50000*rand( p ); p = p*2.02;
        f += 0.25000*rand( p ); p = p*2.03;
        f += 0.12500*rand( p ); p = p*2.01;
        f += 0.06250*rand( p ); p = p*2.04;
        f += 0.03125*rand( p );
        return f/0.984375;
}

float noise( in vec2 x )//Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
    vec2 p = floor(x);
    vec2 f = fract(x);
        f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
        float n = p.x + p.y*57.0;
        float res = mix(mix( hash(n+  0.0), hash(n+  1.0),f.x), mix( hash(n+ 57.0), hash(n+ 58.0),f.x),f.y);
        return res;
}

float fbm( vec2 p ) //Borroowed from Mark Sleith
{
        float f = 0.0;
        f += 0.50000*noise( p ); p = p*2.02;
        f += 0.25000*noise( p ); p = p*2.03;
        f += 0.12500*noise( p ); p = p*2.01;
        f += 0.06250*noise( p ); p = p*2.04;
        f += 0.03125*noise( p );
        return f/0.984375;
}

vec3 bgGradient()
{
    //Getting the height of the current pixel
    float height = gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y;

    //Calculating the brightness of the pixel
    float brightness = 1.0 - 0.4 * height;

    //Combining everything into a background
    vec3 grad = vec3(1., 1., 1.);// * brightness;
    return grad;
}

bool star()
{
    /*//Getting a position to run random calculations with
    float pos = (gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x) * (gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y) + 0.5;

    if(hash(pos) < 0.001)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false*/;

    if(fBmWRand(gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy) < 0.08)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

float cloudFadeDist = 0.1; //The distance at which the clouds will start fading away

vec4 clouds( vec2 point )
{
    vec4 result = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);

    //Checking if the cloud is above
    float fbmResult = fbm(point * 5.);
    if(fbmResult > overcast)
    {
        result = vec4(fbmResult, fbmResult, fbmResult, 1.0);
        //result = vec4(1., 1., 1., 1.);
    }
    else if(fbmResult > overcast - (cloudFadeDist / resFact)) //Outlining the clouds
    {
        float dist = overcast - fbmResult;
        float colorFac = 1.0 - dist / (cloudFadeDist / resFact);

        if(colorFac > 0.0001)
        {
            result = vec4(fbmResult, fbmResult, fbmResult, colorFac);
        }
    }

    //Finer details
    float fbmDetail = fbm(point * 20.);
    vec4 details = vec4( 0.7 + fbmDetail, 0.7 + fbmDetail, 0.7 + fbmDetail, 1.0);

    //result = mix(result, details, result.a);
    result = result * details;
    result = result * details;

    return result;
}

vec2 sunPos = vec2(0.15, 0.1);

float sunWidth = 0.03;
float sunGlow = 0.015;

float sunR = 1.;
float sunG = 1.;
float sunB = 0.8;

vec4 sun()
{
    vec4 result = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    float xPos = gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x;
    float yPos = gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.x;

    float xDist = xPos - sunPos.x;
    float yDist = yPos - sunPos.y;

    float dist = sqrt(pow(xDist, 2.) + pow(yDist, 2.));


    if(dist < sunWidth)
    {
        result = vec4(sunR, sunG, sunB, 1.);
    }
    else if(dist < sunWidth + sunGlow)
    {
        float distFact = (dist - sunWidth) / sunGlow;

        result = vec4(sunR, sunG, sunB , 1. - distFact);
    }

    return result;
}

float nStart = 2200;
float nEnd = 600;
float dStart = 800;
float dEnd = 2000;

void main(void)
{
    //Cretaing the final color variable and adding the gradient
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(bgGradient(), 1.0);

    //Creating stars
    vec4 starLayer = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    if(star() == true)
    {
        starLayer = vec4(1., 1., 1., 1.);   //Make the pixel very bright
    }

    //Generating the clouds
    vec4 cloudLayer = vec4(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //clouds( (15.0 * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy + posX * float(i + 1));
        /*vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2((15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1)),
                            (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResoulution.y);*/

        vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2( (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1),
            (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y + posY * float(i + 1)));

        //finalColor = finalColor + vec4(cloud, 1.);
        cloudLayer = mix(cloudLayer, cloud, cloud.a);
    }

    if(time > nStart || time < nEnd) //Nighttime
    {
        finalColor = finalColor * nSky;

        finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer.a);

        cloudLayer = cloudLayer * nCloud;
        //finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
        vec4 genericColor = cloudLayer;
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
        //finalColor = vec4(nSky.r, nSky.g, nSky.b, 1.0);
    }
    else if(time > dStart && time < dEnd)
    {
        finalColor = finalColor * dSky;

        //cloudLayer = cloudLayer * dCloud;
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
    }
    else if(time > dEnd && time < nStart) //Evening
    {
        float timeFact = (time - dEnd) / (nStart - dEnd);

        //Calculating the diffirence between night and day
        vec4 skyDiff = vec4(nSky.r - dSky.r, nSky.g - dSky.g, nSky.b - dSky.b, 1.);
        vec4 skyColor = vec4(dSky.r + (skyDiff.r * timeFact), dSky.g + (skyDiff.g * timeFact), dSky.b + (skyDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);

        finalColor = skyColor;

        //Stars
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer * timeFact);

        //Clouds
        vec4 cloudDiff = vec4(nCloud.r - dCloud.r, nCloud.g - dCloud.g, nCloud.b - dCloud.b, 1.);
        vec4 cloudColor = vec4(dCloud.r + (cloudDiff.r * timeFact), dCloud.g + (cloudDiff.g * timeFact), dCloud.b + (cloudDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);
        vec4 cloudLayer = cloudLayer * cloudColor;
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
    }
    else if(time > nEnd && time < dStart) //Evening
    {
        float timeFact = (time - nEnd) / (dStart - nEnd);

        //Calculating the diffirence between night and day
        vec4 skyDiff = vec4(dSky.r - nSky.r, dSky.g - nSky.g, dSky.b - nSky.b, 1.);
        vec4 skyColor = vec4(nSky.r + (skyDiff.r * timeFact), nSky.g + (skyDiff.g * timeFact), nSky.b + (skyDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);

        finalColor = skyColor;

        //Stars
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, starLayer, starLayer * 1. - timeFact);

        //Clouds
        vec4 cloudDiff = vec4(dCloud.r - nCloud.r, dCloud.g - nCloud.g, dCloud.b - nCloud.b, 1.);
        vec4 cloudColor = vec4(nCloud.r + (cloudDiff.r * timeFact), nCloud.g + (cloudDiff.g * timeFact), nCloud.b + (cloudDiff.b * timeFact), 1.);
        vec4 cloudLayer = cloudLayer * cloudColor;
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloudLayer, cloudLayer.a);
    }

    //finalColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);

    //vec4 sunColor = sun();
    //finalColor = mix(finalColor, sunColor, sunColor.a);
    //If there is a star
    /*if(star() == true)
    {
        finalColor = vec4(1., 1., 1., 1.);  //Make the pixel very bright
    }*/

    /*for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //clouds( (15.0 * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy + posX * float(i + 1));
        //vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2((15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1)),
                            (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResoulution.y);

        vec4 cloud = clouds( vec2( (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.x / iResolution.x + posX * float(i + 1),
            (15. * float(i)) + gl_FragCoord.y / iResolution.y + posY * float(i + 1)));

        //finalColor = finalColor + vec4(cloud, 1.);
        finalColor = mix(finalColor, cloud, cloud.a);
    }*/

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

And a working version without the time stuff can be found [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lss3WB) to get an idea of what the shader actually does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally shader compilers (being either glsl/hlsl) are pretty good at removing dead code.

So if you calculate some value but don't use it, the compiler will just strip it off before to send the shader bytecode to the graphics card. So in the final compiled version the calculation will actually just not happen.

As soon as you start using this value (which you do as soon as soon you assign it to gl_FragColor) then it's actually "really" integrated in your final shader.

And noise calculations are generally quite ALU intensive, so a slowdown to 300 is not unusual (and actually not even too bad, depending on which card you use).